# all content is display in first column

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns, display

i tried to create a table where in the second row, the close btn is in the first col (the first cell in first row is empty), the grey square and text in product col and price in price col, but as it is display all content is now in first col, while I please someone explain what wrong and give some solution

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.flex, .square_text, section .detail .row .close_btn, section .detail .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section h2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section h2 span {
  color: #00bcd4;
}
section table,
section tr,
section th,
section td {
  border: 1px solid #dfe5e8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
section .detail .head {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #b6c6c9;
}
section .detail .head span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
section .detail .row {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
section .detail .row .close_btn {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
section .detail .row .square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background: #99a9b5;
}
section .detail .row .text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
section .detail .row .text .blue {
  color: #00bcd4;
}
section .detail .row .text .grey {
  color: #cfd7dc;
  font-size: 14px;
}
section .detail .row .price {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #cbcad0;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=price_table.css.map */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/price_table.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h2>you have<span> 6 items </span>in your cart</h2>
      <table class="detail">
        <tr class="head">
          <th class="first_col"></th>
          <th><span>product</span></th>
          <th><span class="price">price</span></th>
          <th><span class="quantity">quantity</span></th>
          <th><span>total</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
          <td><span class="close_btn">x</span></td>
          <td class="square_text">
            <span class="square"></span>
            <p class="text">
              <span class="blue">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
              <span class="grey">size: large, color: black</span>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td><span class="price">$35.99</span></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are applying `display: flex` to the `.square_text` table cells, which is messing things up - table cells _need_ to have display set to `table-cell` for the table layout algorithm to work correctly. If you need flexbox to align your content within a table cell correctly - then wrap the content into an additional container div, and apply flexbox to that.

Answer (score 0):

The `display:flex` was the problem as pointed out by @Cbroe. Its getting applied to your entire row as well as other elements causing issues. Also, If you need to remove the Square box in product you need to remove the `display:inline-block` property from there.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.flex, .square_text, section .detail .row .close_btn, section .detail .row {
  
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section h2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section h2 span {
  color: #00bcd4;
}
section table,
section tr,
section th,
section td {
  border: 1px solid #dfe5e8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
section .detail .head {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #b6c6c9;
}
section .detail .head span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
section .detail .row {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
section .detail .row .close_btn {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
section .detail .row .square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background: #99a9b5;
}
section .detail .row .text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
section .detail .row .text .blue {
  color: #00bcd4;
}
section .detail .row .text .grey {
  color: #cfd7dc;
  font-size: 14px;
}
section .detail .row .price {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #cbcad0;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=price_table.css.map */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/price_table.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h2>you have<span> 6 items </span>in your cart</h2>
      <table class="detail">
        <tr class="head">
          <th class="first_col"></th>
          <th><span>product</span></th>
          <th><span class="price">price</span></th>
          <th><span class="quantity">quantity</span></th>
          <th><span>total</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
          <td><span class="close_btn">x</span></td>
          <td class="square_text">
            <span class="square"></span>
            <p class="text">
              <span class="blue">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
              <span class="grey">size: large, color: black</span>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td><span class="price">$35.99</span></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```